# Redistribution of Linux Distribution?

Tags: distributions, gpl

If a Linux Distribution is under GPL, and I would redistribute it, is it correct that I only need to be able to give the sources? For example, say I build a 4-in-1 multi distribution DVD (I got sick of burning 4 separate discs so I made it multi-bootable). Could I distribute it for others to use without facing a lawsuit?

Comment: The GPL affects redistribution: Yes, you could distribute the GPL'd components if you provide the source code, or a means for users to request the source code. And in turn, so could others re-distribute the GPL'd components you provided in the same way.

Comment: (But you'll have to be careful with components which are not under GPL, or under a free license at all, such as proprietary drivers.)

Comment: Actually if you are just distributing say a Debian, or a Ubuntu, do you need to redistribute all the source that is already available everywhere, or just the source of the modifications you made (for instance an util for making  new graphical interface?) I could swear it is the latter situation.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro The page that the answer links to says: "For instance, when you host object code on a web or FTP server, you can simply provide instructions that tell visitors how to get the source from a third-party server. Thanks to this new option, fulfilling this requirement should be easier for many small distributors who only make a few changes to large bodies of source." Seems to me, the latter (note: third party). You see this in action in some Debian package source repositories, where the upstream code is not kept but only patches and packaging code.

Comment: While we've traditionally tolerated questions about licensing, there is now a site [opensource.se] which would be far more appropriate for this question. Do not repost there. If you want, moderators can migrate your question; use the “flag” button and “in need of moderator intervention” to request that.

Answer (score 0):

I read http://www.gnu.org/licenses/quick-guide-gplv3.html and interpret it as clearly saying that you need to include the sources:

```
 Both versions of the GPL require you to provide all the source necessary to build the software, including supporting libraries, compilation scripts, and so on.
```

The same page also summarises the exceptions, i.e. cases in which you do not have to include sources.

Thus: if the distribution is under a current GPL version then you should include the sources when redistributing it and/or modifying it.

Comment: I believe however that the exact wording is "on request". I can choose to mail it to you on CD or whatever. Just has to be in a useful, machine readable format.